# How do I send all selected data from the drop-down menu to the server with a "post" method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http

I have multiple data and am trying to figure out how to send all selected data via a method "post" call in order to query that information from a server and send it back. For now I've been experimenting with forms, yet am sure there is a much simpler way to do this. Please be so kind as show to explain to me a version that takes in all the selected options chosen by the user.

**Running Code:** When running the script, user must cause a change in the first dropdown. This would create a second drop-down. In order to create a third drop-down, you must again invoke a change in the first dropdown(would fix this soon).

**Logic:** The reasoning behind this script is to take in multiple strings to search in a database and send it off to be processed after the button "Search" is clicked.

```
<pre>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>Query Tool</title>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var selector = 0;
//var arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#select" + selector).change(function() {
            //$.post('where',{data},function (d) {     //this is to post data to the server and get the answer with function
                // documentation is at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/
                // if the answer is in JSON, decode it
                var answer = '[{"ID":"1","name":"None"},{"ID":"2","name":"Ship Type"},{"ID":"3","name":"Anomoly Type"},{"ID":"4","name":"MMSI"}]';
                var d = JSON.parse(answer);
                selector++;
                var s = $("<select id=\"select_two\" name=\"select_two\" />");
                for(var val in d) {
                    $("<option />", {value: d[val].ID, text: d[val].name}).appendTo(s);
                }
                $("#select" + selector).empty();
                s.appendTo("#select" + selector);
            //}); // closing brackets for the post method
        });
        //document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", displayDate);


    });
    function PostData() {
        var formElement = document.forms["myform"];
        var array = [];
        //$.post("form.html");
         for(var val in selector) {
                    //string = formElement.elements[val].value;
                array.concat(formElement.elements[val].value);
                    //alert(formElement.elements[val].value);//can I print out the options selected?

         }
        alert(array.length);//can I print out the options selected?


    }

</script>
</head>
<body><br>
    <p>Testing.</p>
    <h1>Organizer Tool</h1>
<HR>
<p>Please choose search criteria:</p>
<form name = "myform" action="index.html">
<select id="select0">
    <option value="None">None</option>
    <option value="Ship Type">Ship Type</option>
    <option value="Anomaly Type">Anomaly Type</option>
    <option value="MMSI">MMSI</option>
</select>
<div id="select1"></div>
<div id="select2"></div>
<div id="select3"></div>
<div id="select4"></div>
<div id="select5"></div>
<div id="select6"></div>
<div id="select7"></div>
<div id="select8"></div>
<div id="select9"></div>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick = "PostData()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
</pre>
```

Comment: So, I'm having a little trouble understanding the question... you say multiple forms, but I think you just mean multiple select elements?  But if you're just looking for a way to package up all the fields/controls in your form to send it to the server you might look at the jQuery [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method.

Comment: There are many tutorials on using jQuery for AJAX. They should show how to do this.

Comment: Multiple selects? If you can show me a way to send through all the selects that would be awesome! I may have over analyzed it if I don't need to worry about multiple forms..

Comment: So the question has been reworded; sorry for the confusion. If any of you would be so kind to look it over, let me know if it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Remove the `<pre>` surrounding the page. `<pre>` are used to render text without format. So if you have text to the very edge of a webpage, normally, it would wrap nicely, space itself properly, etc. Any text within `<pre>` will render as it is typed on the document, so in a nutshell don't even use `<pre>` until you fully comprehend what it it does. In fact, do not wrap `<html>` tags with any other tag. `<html>` is supposed to be the top tag of the page, it's the mothership of all HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you need to post from a form at the very minimal:

1. At least one `<form id="process1" name="process1">`
2. One `<input type="submit">`
3. Any form element with the `name=` attribute

Even though this way doesn't need any JavaScript, I wrote some in order to populate those 8 inputs (originally you made them into divs). This Snippet will post the value of **any form element** that has a `name` and has data. I have provided an iframe that will display what the server received from the form. The server's purpose is for testing posts, but it doesn't respond (hence the iframe).

#### USAGE

1. Select up to 8 items from the `<select>`.
2. Click the `<submit>` button
3. In the iframe, there should be some raw text reporting what the server received.

Due to SO strict security, the Snippet doesn't work as expected. Review this [<kbd>PLUNKER</kbd>](http://embed.plnkr.co/vGLbIwjOHbrlQfrZRDK0/) instead.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Query Tool</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function() {
      var selected = "";
      var count = 0;
      var outputs = $('[name="output"]');
      var current;
      $('#select0').on('change', function() {
        if (count < outputs.length) {
          current = outputs.eq(count);
          count++;
          selected = $(this).val();
          current.val(selected);
        } else return;
      });
    });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <form id="process1" name="process1" action="http://www.hashemian.com/tools/form-post-tester.php/tesso/" target='frame1' method='post'>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>
        <h1>Form Post Test</h1>
      </legend>

      <figure class='fig'>
        <figcaption>This is an iframe that will display whatever the server has received from this form. Unfortunately this will not function because SO sandbox security is too strict</figcaption>
        <iframe id='frame1' name='frame1' src='about:blank' width='98%'></iframe>
      </figure>

      <fieldset>
        <select id="select0" name="select0">
          <option value="Ship Type">Ship Type</option>
          <option value="Anomaly Type">Anomaly Type</option>
          <option value="MMSI">MMSI</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit">
      </fieldset>
      <br/>
      <br/>
      <label for='select1'>Select 1:</label>
      <input id="select1" name='output'>
      <br/>
      <label for='select2'>Select 2:</label>
      <input id="select2" name='output'>
      <br/>
      <label for='select3'>Select 3:</label>
      <input id="select3" name='output'>
      <br/>
      <label for='select4'>Select 4:</label>
      <input id="select4" name='output'>
      <br/>
      <label for='select5'>Select 5:</label>
      <input id="select5" name='output'>
      <br/>
      <label for='select6'>Select 6:</label>
      <input id="select6" name='output'>
      <br/>
      <label for='select7'>Select 7:</label>
      <input id="select7" name='output'>
      <br/>
      <label for='select8'>Select 8:</label>
      <input id="select8" name='output'>
      <br/>
      <br/>

    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you this was very useful! I think what should be done is create a php file which would query the selected values and return it onto the main page.

Comment: You very welcome. Sounds like a solid plan, unfortunately I'm only front-end and know very little server-side stuff like PHP. I'm sure you'll get plenty of help with another question, just make sure you include a PHP tag, happy coding.